# How to use column values from sql database as parameters of python function?

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to check weather the years in one of the column of my table movie is a leap year or not. If yes i want to the name of the movie corresponding to  it.

I have tried the following code

```
def leap_year(year):
    if year%4==0:
        if(year%100==0):
            if(year%400==0):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True           
    else:
        return False

result=pd.read_sql_query("select m.name from movie m where m.year = {}".format(leap_year(m.year)),conn)

print(result)
```

I know it does not work as i can't directly pass m.year, but i tried to find but could not get the right syntax to do this.

Comment: What is your table format? What are the columns? Your first step should be to write a static query that works. Then turn that query to python. You probably want to do something like: `...where m.year = \'{}\'".format(leap_year)...` though `m.year` does not sound valid.

Comment: i'm confused. you're trying to select the year from the database where the year is equal to the year?

Comment: so movie table has following columns : name , year . I want to retrieve the year value from the column and use it in my function leap_year and check if its leap or not. if its leap i want to print the name of the movie corresponding to that year. ofcourse there are many movies in one year

Answer (score 0):

Use `calendar`

```
import calendar

def leapyear(year):
    result = calendar.isleap(year)
    if result == True:
        print(str(year) + ' is a leap year')
    else:
        print(str(year) + ' is not a leap year')

leapyear(2018)
```

use your sql column's year as the year input for the function

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you're trying to do with your code... But here, this is the best I could think up

```
import sqlite3

def leap_year(year):
    if year%4==0:
        if(year%100==0):
            if(year%400==0):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return True;

    else:
        return False

with sqlite3.connect("db.db") as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT m.year FROM movie WHERE m.year = ?", (leap_year(m.year)))
    results = cur.fetchall()
    for result in results:
        print(result)
```

Comment: You can adjust the values, considering it made no sense originally I don't intend to make sense of it myself lol

Answer (score 0):

First select all of the years and movie names from your table. The way you have it set up now is filtering it to a single year which isn't what it sounds like you want.

```
results = pd.read_sql_query("select name, year from movies", con=conn)
```

Now go through each year in the results and run the leap year function over it.

```
import calendar

for index, row in results.iterrows():
    if calendar.isleap(row['year']):
        print(row['name'])
```